# Is there an R package for correcting for multiple testing in GLM's, specifically for relative risk or risk difference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model

In my study I am looking at sex differences in the efficacy of biologicals (=type of medicine) in patients with axial spondyloarthritis. I am looking at different 7 different outcomes (disease activity scores) at time 6, 12 and 24 months. I am using a GLM with binomial family to calculate relative risk and risk difference. I wish to make the confidence intervals broader, since I wish to correct for multiple testing.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is a small representative dataset and the code I ran:

```r
    dat <- structure(list(gender = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), age_std = structure(c(-0.467384378359854, 
    -0.623520001679169, 0.703632796535007, -0.935791248317799, -1.16999468329677, 
    1.32817528981227, -1.16999468329677, 0.235225926577062, -0.857723436658141, 
    -0.389316566700197, -0.467384378359854, -0.31124875504054, -1.24806249495643, 
    -1.09192687163711, -0.623520001679169, -1.40419811827574, -1.79453717657403, 
    -1.71646936491437, -1.87260498823369, -1.09192687163711), .Dim = c(20L, 
    1L)), bio_drug_start_year_centered = c(-6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -9, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), country = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CH", "CZ", "DK", "ES", "IS", "IT", "NL", 
    "NO", "PT", "RO", "SE", "SF", "SI", "TR", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
        bio_drug_start_year = c(2007, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2004, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2016, 2015, 2013, 2015, 
        2013, 2013, 2014, 2013), asdas_crp_cii_6month = c(1, 1, 0, 
        1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)), na.action = structure(c(`114174` = 2755L, 
    `116484` = 2770L, `231118` = 3050L), class = "omit"), row.names = c("463", 
    "7729", "7756", "8306", "8324", "128", "8440", "8450", "8663", 
    "8809", "8840", "8857", "9020", "9033", "9101", "9324", "9377", 
    "9523", "9702", "9718"), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
    rr = rd = numeric()
    for( i in 1: 1e3){
      logmod = glm( asdas_crp_cii_6month ~ gender + country + 
          age_std + bio_drug_start_year_centered, 
                    family = 'binomial', data = 
    dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat),replace=T),])
      summary(logmod)
      dat.1 = dat.0 = dat
      dat.1$gender = 1
      dat.0$gender = 0
      p1 = predict(logmod, newdata = dat.1, 'response' )
      p0 = predict(logmod, newdata = dat.0, 'response' )
      rr[i] = mean(p1)/mean(p0)
      rd[i] = mean(p1)-mean(p0)
    }
    twosidep <- function(data, test = 0) {
      p1 <- sum(data>test)/length(data)
      p2 <- sum(data<test)/length(data)
      p <- min(p1,p2)*2
      return(p)
    }
    m = rbind(c(mean(rr), quantile(rr, c(0.025, 0.975)), 
    twosidep(rr, test = 1) ),
              c(mean(rd), quantile(rd, c(0.025, 0.975)), 
    twosidep(rd) ))
    rownames(m) = c('rr', 'rd')
    colnames(m) = c('Estimate', 'Lower CI', 'Upper CI', 
                    'p-value')
    m
```

Here is output of the code

```r
         Estimate   Lower CI  Upper CI   p-value
    rr  0.7746110  0.3413350 1.3527440 0.6666667
    rd -0.2103283 -0.6420473 0.1899121 0.6666667
```

**Question: How can I increase these confidence intervals?**

Comment: The famous software is named R not r! I did a correction ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to move away from individual models for each outcome/time combination. Also, if you have "disease activity scores" and are translating them to 0/1 outcomes for this model, you will probably be better off modeling the scores directly instead. The closer you are to modeling the original data the better your model will typically be.

There are several ways to handle repeated measurements within individuals, nicely summarized in a table in the chapter on "Modeling Longitudinal Responses with Generalized Least Squares" in Frank Harrell's [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) or [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/). If your "disease activity scores" are sufficiently continuous and appropriately distributed you could use the generalized least squares approach he describes there.

One alternative would be a mixed model that treats individuals as random effects. Those are implemented for example in the R [`lme4` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4). [Generalized estimating equations](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/lesson/12/12.1) (GEE) can also account for repeated measurements. Those are implemented for example in the R [`geepack` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=geepack). GEE might be more like what you are asking for, as GEE regression coefficient estimates are generally unchanged from standard models but their associated variance estimates are adjusted for the repeated measures. Both approaches can be used with generalized linear models if you need them.

Depending on the nature of your data you could set up such models in different ways. I might lean toward a single giant model for *all* your observations across all outcomes. Differences among outcome measures would be handled by including the type of outcome as one of your predictors along with time, including an interaction for each type of outcome with your primary predictor of interest, sex. In a mixed model you could include individual-specific random effects for both the intercepts and "slopes" (outcome-specific coefficients). The other extreme would be separate models for each type of outcome, perhaps using some multiple-comparison correction across the outcomes, but that would tend to ignore the correlations among different outcomes within an individual.

This seems sufficiently important, complicated, and dependent on the details of your data for you to try to get a local statistical expert to help with the project.

Comment: First thanks for taking the time to respond. Second, even though I agree that from a statistical point of modeling original data is better than categorical data, from a clinical point of view, categorical data is superior as it has meaning to the physician. Third, I am not interested in changing my methodology. In fact, as you suggested, this methodology has already been discussed and agreed in concordance with a local statistician. However he is indisposed as he is currently busy with other project but he has suggested that I use a multiple-comparison correction, hence my question.

Comment: @Pashtun the best way to deal with the second point is to model original data as much as possible and reduce to categorical at the last stage of presenting results. For the third point, you might need GEE or mixed models to account for intra-individual associations within outcomes, as multiple-comparison correction might not handle that. [This paper](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0754-4) discusses multiple-comparison correction methods, implemented in R, to handle multiple outcomes.

Comment: @Pashtun [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/5/5/394/htm) gets directly at adjusting odds-ratio CI for multiple comparisons, explained for the Hochberg step-up correction method but presumably also applicable to the Hommel method favored in the paper linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Appreciate the response. We have chosen to look at the proportion of females that have achieved "clinically important improvement" which is 1.1 or more point improvement on outcome and compare this proportion with males. This is clinically more relevant than say an improvement of X points. As for the second part, could you explain what you mean with intra-individual associations? Problems with modelling a GEE is that the data gets more biased as time goes on. For example, sex differences become smaller as time progresses, as the females with worse outcome drop out.

Comment: Therefore, we have chosen one primary endpoint and one timepoint as primary: 6 months. The rest is all secondary data. I think this is more reliable. Thanks for the paper will have a look at it.

Comment: @Pashtun you could deal with sex differences becoming smaller over time by explicitly modeling changes over time in your original point scale (e.g., slope over time) and including an interaction between that slope and sex. Or treat time-to-event with a survival model. With only a single endpoint and timepoint you don't need to worry abut multiple-comparison correction or "intra-individual associations." The latter term was meant to describe [repeated measures](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/lesson/4/4.2/4.2.1) so that measurements over time or among different outcomes aren't independent.